# Select div container in JQuery BlockUI message

Tags: jquery, blockui, jquery-blockui

I am using this Plugin in order to block the UI when `<input type="submit">` is clicked. However I don't want to block UI immediately, but 2 seconds later.

The following function doesn't work because `$('#processingData')` cannot be found, although I have defined `<h3 id="ProcessingData" style="display:none">Processing Data...</h3>` in the html body.

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.blockUI({ 
                message: $('#processingData')
            }); 
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Comment: a quick guess is you should use message: $('#processingData').text()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dunno if this is just a typo in your question, but `processingData`and `ProcessingData` is not the same. Notice the capital P at the beginning.

And shouldn't it be

```
message: $('#ProcessingData').text()
```

?

Comment: thank you very much, I was so stupid! That should be 'processingData' not 'ProcessingData' !

Comment: yes and no, I mean not exactly, It is the feature of BlockUI. The message can be plain text and text with styles. That means, the input here can be the whole html fragement: <h3 id="ProcessingData" style="display:none">Processing Data...</h3>  You're right, I had mixed up the 'P' and 'p'. Thank you once again! ;)